# When using views to create a list of nodes, how can I eliminate the link from the node title?

Tags: views, 6

I am using views to create a list of nodes. I am using the "Unformatted" style, with the "Node" row style.

This is perfect for my need *except* that it automatically creates a link from each node title to the node page. I would like to not have those links.

How can I most easily do this? Would the best way to be to switch to "Field" row style and simply include the fields I want, styled the way I want? Or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select node style, it uses your node.tpl.php file to create the node, so if that has a link in the title, it's gonna be there.  You can choose the "style" of node, eg, teaser or full, to change this behavior, and include or not include links and comments, etc.  Or, as you ask, go to Fields and have a lot more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

A very good option to have reusable rendering templates is to use [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds), it allows you to define arbitrary view modes for your node types and use them easily in views. The issue with the linked title is very easy to solve in display suite by just editing the options for the title field in the appropriate view mode.

Note: to use arbitrary view modes in D6 it's necessary to select the Display Suite node renderer for the row style, not the default one.

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful to know. While we've gone down the route of using a customized node-type.tpl.php file, it's good to know of this alternative.